# How to measure data transfer rate between two nodes on Linux Server ? Must ignore the effect of disk

Tags: linux, performance, performance-testing, ethernet

At first , I use **scp** to copy a file from node9 to node10 .But this method does not satisfied with my purposes.Cause **scp** will be affected by the disk.Result in unexpected result.So , What should I do ? My ethernet is 10Gbit/s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things... firstly, `scp` is encrypted and also takes time therefore to encrypt, so consider using `nc` or `netcat` which is installed on most Linux distros. Secondly, you can use `/dev/zero` to generate data very fast. So...

**Generate data fast**

Let's generate 10 GBytes of data from `/dev/zero` and discard to `/dev/null` to check how fast we can generate data:

```
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1024k count=10000 > /dev/null
10000+0 records in
10000+0 records out
10485760000 bytes transferred in 0.573830 secs (18273282446 bytes/sec)
```

None too shabby at 18 GBytes/sec.

**Transfer across network**

Now, on node10, prepare to receive the data by listening on port 8000, and then  discarding the received data:

```
nc -l 8000 > /dev/null
```

And on, on node9, send the data and time it:

```
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1024k count=10000 | nc node10 8000
```

Comment: Thank you,my bro.I will use your method on my server and test it.Your method can ignore disk IO ? And I want to invite you to look my solution about this problem by using netperf. OKay ? My test result is 9409.88 Mb/s Theoretical value is 10000Mb/s.

Comment: Correct, there is no disk i/o involved in my solution - and no software to install :-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I have solve this problem by using netperf.And here is the website of this software.[enter link description here](http://www.netperf.org/netperf/)

Test results 9409.88 Mb/s
Theoretical value 10000Mb/s